# jquery ui tabs slide up effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, slideup

I have jquery ui tabs set up but I want to add a slide up and slide down animation. Currently when you click the button it just opens and closes. How do I add the slide effect to my existing jquery code?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".tabs").tabs({
        collapsible: true,
        active: 'none'
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code

HTML

```
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Content for Tab 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Content for Tab 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Content for Tab 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="tabid"></div>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $.effects.effect.heightFade = function(o, done) {
    var el = $(this),
      mode = $.effects.setMode(el, o.mode || "show");
    el.animate({
      height: mode,
      opacity: mode
    }, {
      queue: false,
      complete: done
    });
  };

  $(".tabs").tabs({
    collapsible: true,
    active: 'none',
    hide: "heightFade",
    show: "heightFade",
  });
  return false;
});
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/gpeczyff/1/